# ECTO + Kinect Issue

Tags: ros, openni, pcl, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to run a VERY basic ECTO cell before I integrate in any of my own functionality I am getting the following error:

```
python example.py 
Connecting to device.
 attempting to turn on registration...
Failed to start generating.Bad Parameter sent to the device!
303:/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-ecto-openni-0.3.8-0precise-20130313-1459/cells/Capture.cpp

Connected to device.
Failed to update all contexts.A timeout has occurred when waiting for new data!
430:/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-ecto-openni-0.3.8-0precise-20130313-1459/cells/Capture.cpp

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am not sure what is causing this as I am simply using ECTO to access the Kinect and to display the point cloud. I have attached the source for the example.py file below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ecto
import ecto_openni
import ecto_pcl

plasm = ecto.Plasm()

# capture from kinect and downsample
device = ecto_openni.Capture( 'device' )
cloud_generator = ecto_pcl.NiConverter('cloud_generator')
viewer = ecto_pcl.CloudViewer( "viewer", window_name="Clouds!" )

graph = [ device[:] >> cloud_generator[:],
          cloud_generator[:] >> viewer[:]
        ]

plasm.connect( graph )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from ecto.opts import doit
    doit(plasm, description='test.')
```

Above this line has been resolved.

---

I have updated my python code to include the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ecto, ecto_pcl, ecto_ros, ecto_pcl_ros

from ecto_openni import Capture

plasm = ecto.Plasm()

# capture from kinect and downsample
cloud_sub = ecto_sensor_msgs.Subscriber_PointCloud2("cloud_sub", topic_name='/camera/depth_registered/points')
msg2cloud = ecto_pcl_ros.Message2PointCloud("msg2cloud", format=ecto_pcl.XYZRGB)

cloud2msg = ecto_pcl_ros.PointCloud2Message("cloud2msg")
cloud_pub = ecto_sensor_msgs.Publisher_PointCloud2("cloud_pub",topic_name='/ecto_pcl/sample_output')

plasm.connect( cloud_sub['output'] >> msg2cloud[:],
               msg2cloud[:] >> cloud2msg[:],
               cloud2msg[:] >> cloud_pub[:] )

ecto_ros.init(sys.argv, "get_point_cloud")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from ecto.opts import doit
    doit(plasm, description='Read a pcd through ROS.')
```

When I run this code I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ros_example.py", line 10, in <module>
    cloud_sub = ecto_sensor_msgs.Subscriber_PointCloud2("cloud_sub", topic_name='/camera/depth_registered/points')
NameError: name 'ecto_sensor_msgs' is not defined
```

I am also not sure if I am performing the call to ecto_ros.init() properly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60008/ecto-+-kinect-issue/) by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your first case seems to be a bug, please file one on https://github.com/plasmodic/ecto_openni/issues to keep track of it (I am also looking into it at the same time).

We usually do not use the raw openni wrapper but create_source ("from ecto_image_pipeline.io.source import create_source") but that would not work with PCL indeed.

The second is incomplete code, you forgot a "from ecto_ros import ecto_sensor_msgs" and you also need to call "ecto_ros.init(sys.argv, "Whatever")" at first as mentioned on the docs here: http://plasmodic.github.io/ecto_ros/

That second code works for me. Please file a bug if that is not the case for you.

UPDATE: ok, to answer one of the  comments, ecto is definitely maintained, not necessarily developed (I will update the docs for that):

- ecto had specs that were met and we have not found a core bug in two years (yeah, crazy ...)
- ecto_ros is mostly autogenerated publishers/subscribers/bad tools around ROS msgs. So nothing to really add (if you think so, please file a bug report)
- ecto_pcl is not really used anywhere but we can definitely wrap more functionalities.
- ecto_openni is a wrapper around the OpenNI driver which has been stable for a while, except we usually use the OpenNICapture (bad naming) which works with OpenCV
- ecto_opencv wraps old or upcoming OpenCV functionalities so we update it once in a while
- ecto_image_pipeline is a re-write of image_pipeline in ecto and we should probably simply merge it upstream

So, on the ecto side, it's pretty stable and all the nodelets from image_common, image_pipeline, pcl_ros vision_opencv should use it for stability increase (ecto is basically ROS-agnostic Python/C++ stable nodelets with a scheduler). We're kindof waiting on when they'll ask the community about what ROS 2.0 should have before changing everything.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2013-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on 2013-04-06**:
I have opened an issue for the first one here: https://github.com/plasmodic/ecto_openni/issues/5 and I will try to fix the second and let you know if that solves it in the next little bit.

**Comment by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on 2013-04-06**:
Is ecto still under active development? When I look at the GitHub pages for PCL, OpenNI and ROS there doesn't seem to have been any work on them in the last month or so I am just curious as we just want to ensure it is still something under active development and use :)